# How to make one time changing state pulse?

Tags: integrated-circuit, flipflop, signal-generator, virtuoso

I'm undergraduate learning the analog circuit design. I want to make a signal that changes its state only one time
when the input pulse signal changes its state at first.

I'm trying to use D-flip flop, but it's hard to think of any element which can be used in virtuoso is fine.

[image]

Comment: You need a bistable flip-flop. A simple SR latch would work.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to use D-flip flop*

Wire your input to the D type clock. Put the D input to zero and take your output from \$\bar{Q}\$. Make sure you apply a power-on reset to the D type so it settles down to the correct state.